# How to open ReplyKeyboardMarkup by clicking InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I need to open `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` by clicking on `InlineKeyboardButton` using [library](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots).

In my case, click on `Create post` button 
[image]

And open this type of keyboard
[image]

So, I'm trying to click `InlineKeyboardButton` and open `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` using `CallbackQuery` (to handle click) like in this [snippet](https://pastebin.com/zdwhKsVc).

When I click on my button, I see only the clock like on the screen (but I have `CallbackQuery` to handle this button):

[image]

```
   else if (call_data.equals("correcting_post")) {
                ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
                List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
                KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
                row.add("Clear");
                row.add("Preview");
                keyboard.add(row);
                row = new KeyboardRow();
                row.add("Cancel");
                row.add("Next");
                keyboard.add(row);
                keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
                AnswerCallbackQuery a = new AnswerCallbackQuery()
                        .setCallbackQueryId(update.getCallbackQuery().getId());
                try {
                    execute(a);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

What I need to correct or add? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right you want to click on one of `InlineKeyboardButton` buttons and then open `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`. In order to do it you can use code like this:

```
public class YourClass extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            String data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
            if (data.equals("correcting_post")) {
                try {
                    ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
                    List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
                    KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
                    row.add("Test button");
                    keyboard.add(row);
                    keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

                    // Create a message object
                    SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                            .setChatId(update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId())
                            .enableMarkdown(true)
                            .setText("Message text");
                    message.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);
                    execute(message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    //exception handling
                }
            }
            //Check another options for data
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Probably this library provides a more convenient way for doing so, but at least this peace of code works.